# How to show labels above the bar chart using chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts

I created bar charts using chart.js which is working fine but I need to add label above the bar.

Any 1 can help me 
Suggestion are most welcome

chart.js version 1.2

Following canvas used for bar chart

```
 <canvas id="barChart" height="180"></canvas>
```

Following code for initiating plugin

```
 var barChartCanvas = $("#barChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
  var barChart = new Chart(barChartCanvas);



var barChartData = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Electronics",
        fillColor: "rgb(210, 214, 222)",
        strokeColor: "rgb(210, 214, 222)",
        pointColor: "rgb(210, 214, 222)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#c1c7d1",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgb(220,220,220)",
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
      },
      {
        label: "Digital Goods",
        fillColor: "rgba(60,141,188,0.9)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(60,141,188,0.8)",
        pointColor: "#3b8bba",
        pointStrokeColor: "rgba(60,141,188,1)",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(60,141,188,1)",
        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
      }
    ]
  };



 var barChartOptions = {
    showScale: true,
    scaleShowGridLines: false,
    scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
    scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
    scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,
    scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
    bezierCurve: true,
    bezierCurveTension: 0.3,
    pointDot: false,
    pointDotRadius: 4,
    pointDotStrokeWidth: 1,
    pointHitDetectionRadius: 20,
    datasetStroke: true,
    datasetStrokeWidth: 2,
    datasetFill: true,
    legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].lineColor%>\"></span><%=datasets [i].label%></li><%}%></ul>",
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: true,
  };


  barChart.Bar(barChartData, barChartOptions);
```

Comment: Check this. https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/327

Comment: I use this code but this code is totally customize for chart.js which is too old (2013) and I am using version 1.2 (2015) so my other charts are also conflict by this So that solution is not properly working for me and it cause for some other issues too....